# How to transfer reward token to contract in Test Case

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I am working on a sample contract which should provide a reward for the user. The winner gets the reward as Token.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
   
pragma solidity ^0.8.5;

contract LeagueWinners {

struct Winner {
    bool exists;
    bool claimed;
    uint256 reward;
}

mapping(address=>Winner) public winners;
mapping (address => bool) private AuthAccounts;

IERC20 private rewardTokenAddr;


modifier onlyAuthAccounts() {
    require(AuthAccounts[msg.sender], "Auth: caller is not the authorized");
    _;
}

constructor (address _rewardTokenAddr) {
    rewardTokenAddr = IERC20(_rewardTokenAddr);
    AuthAccounts[msg.sender] = true;
    AuthAccounts[_addr_1] = true;
    AuthAccounts[_addr_2] = true;
}


function addWinner(address _address, uint256 _amount ) public {
       Winner storage winner = winners[_address];
       winner.exists = true;
       winner.reward = _amount;
   }


function claimPrize() public {
    Winner storage winner = winners[msg.sender];
    require(winner.exists, "Not a winner");
    require(!winner.claimed, "Winner already claimed");
    winner.claimed = true;
    rewardTokenAddr.safeTransfer(msg.sender, winner.tokenAmount);
}

}
```

Test cases is failing when the user is trying to claim the prize. I assume there is no reward token in the contract so its failing.

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const hre = require("hardhat");

describe("LeagueWinners", function () {
  let rewardTokenAddr = "0xAddr.....";
  
  before(async () => {
    LeagueWinners = await ethers.getContractFactory("LeagueWinners");
    leagueWiners = await LeagueWinners.deploy(rewardTokenAddr);
    await leagueWiners.deployed();
    [owner, winner1, winner2, nonwinner] = await ethers.getSigners();
  });

  it("Claim Tokens to be deployed and verify owner", async function () {
    expect(await leagueWiners.owner()).to.equal(owner.address);
  });

  it("Add Winner", async function () {
    winner = await leagueWiners
      .connect(owner)
      .addWinner(
        "winner1.address",
        "50000000000000000000"
      );
  });

  it("Confirm Winner Added with proper reward", async function () {
    winner = await leagueWiners.winners(winner1.address);
    expect(winner.reward).to.equal("50000000000000000000");
  });

  it("Non winner cannot claim", async function () {
    await expect(
      leagueWiners.connect(nonwinner).claimReward()).to.be.revertedWith("Not a winner");
  });

  it("Winner to claim", async function () {
    await leagueWiners.connect(winner1).claimPrize();
    winner = await leagueWiners.winners(winner1.address);
    expect(winner.claimed).to.equal(true);
  });

});
```

Error:

Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Address: call to non-contract'

This line is causing the error
***await leagueWiners.connect(winner1).claimReward();***

Comment: Is the rewardTokenAddr correct? Could you verify it?

Answer (score 0):

From the smart contract source that you provided I see that the name of function is `claimPrize()` not `claimReward()`

Maybe can work if you change to:

```
leagueWiners.connect(winner1).claimPrize();
```

Comment: Still the same error.